# Unbalance and small dataset for image classification

Tags: dataset, classification, conv-neural-network, k-means

I have two datasets of images for classification :

- Damage chocolate packing of 27 images
- Undamaged chocolate packing of 161 images

I have to write a python classifier to distinguish both and alarm production.

What is the best way to solve my problem ? a CNN with transfer learning or a K-mean solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have really few data. For me, transfer learning is the best way to tackle this. However, try to find more data or use data augmentation (you can read [this](https://medium.com/nanonets/how-to-use-deep-learning-when-you-have-limited-data-part-2-data-augmentation-c26971dc8ced)).

Also, if you are looking for transfer learning with CNN, I think [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-transfer-learning-for-beginners-6c9b8b7143e) can help you.